# Why does my empty div collapse although it has a width when display inline is used?

Tags: html, css

WHen I use display inline to place div#hlogo,div#hdesign and div#hTestimonial, the div collapse although I 've set a width on them..

HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org    /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Slicing</title>

</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="hlogo">
                <div class="Hlogo">

                    <div id="Logoheader">RamblingSoul</div>
                    <div id="Logodesc">
                        <p> A Free CSS Template From </p>
                        <p>RamblingSoul</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

        </div>
        <div id="hdesign">

        </div>
        <div id="hTestimonial">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="body">
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS :

```
html,body{  
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;

    }
div#wrapper{    
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        line-height:normal;
        border: #060 thick groove;
        background-color:#FF3;
        font-size:10px;
        line-height:1.5px;
    }

div#wrapper div#header{
        width:100%;
        height:30%;
        border:#F00 medium double;

    }


div#wrapper div#body{
        width:100%;
        height:50%;
        border:#F00 medium double;

    }

div#wrapper div#footer{
        width:100%;
        height:20.0%;
        border:#F00 medium double;

    }



div#wrapper div#header div#hlogo{
        width:30%;
        height:100%;
        border:#F00 medium double;
        //float:left;
        margin:0px ;
    }

div#wrapper div#header div#hdesign{
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        border:#F00 medium double;
        //float:left;
        margin:0px 250px;
    }

div#wrapper div#header div#hTestimonial{
        //width:40%;

        width:30%;
        height:100%;
        border:#F00 medium double;
        float:right;

    }

    div#wrapper div#header div#hlogo,div#wrapper div#header     div#hdesign,div#wrapper div#header div#hTestimonial{display:inline;}
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? What do you think `display: inline` does?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because that's what the spec says to do.

> ### [Content width: the 'width' property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-width-property)
>
> This property does not apply to
>   non-replaced inline elements. The
>   content width of a non-replaced inline
>   element's boxes is that of the
>   rendered content within them (before
>   any relative offset of children).

Comment: to use empty div in a meaningful way. For us, we use an empty div with a background image and we're not sure about the best/right code for it.... Usually, it should be inlined with other text/image/divs...

Comment: @TomFishman - Well, `display:inline-block` might be one way, or use `padding` to fill out the inline element to the required size. But I suggest asking a new SO question to get the best advice.